# Why is there the compile error, " ; expected " for my Java Code?

Tags: java, hashmap

I really do not understand why I am getting this compile error after the parentheses for `"Map<String, Integer> buildTable(){"`.
Here is the code I am working on: I already have the city class defined.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CityMap{

public static void main(String[] args){  
  String _city;
  Map<String, Integer> cityTable = buildTable();

  Map<String, Integer> buildTable(){
     String aCity;
     Map<String, Command> result = new HashMap<String, Command>();

     aCity = new City();
     result.put("NYC", 100000);


     aCity = new City();
     result.put("Boston", 500);

      return result;
 }
```

I am a beginner, so any explanation is welcome.

Comment: You cannot declare methods inside of other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaration for buildTable needs to live outside of your method declaration for main.

I.E.,

```
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.HashMap;

public class CityMap{

public static void main(String[] args)
{  
  String _city;
  Map<String, Integer> cityTable = buildTable();
}

public static Map<String, Integer> buildTable(){
 String aCity;
 Map<String, Command> result = new HashMap<String, Command>();

 aCity = new City();
 result.put("NYC", 100000);


 aCity = new City();
 result.put("Boston", 500);

  return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot declare methods inside of other methods.

Move your `buildTable` method outside of the `main` method (and then you have to either make it `static` or create an object instance to call it from `main`).

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args){} is a method, after all. For this reason you cannot declare another method inside it.

Also, your compiler gets confused when you return result because although it is intended for your buildTable() method, it is placed inside your main() method.

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args){  
  String _city;
  Map<String, Integer> cityTable = buildTable();
}

Map<String, Integer> buildTable(){
 String aCity;
 Map<String, Command> result = new HashMap<String, Command>();

 aCity = new City();
 result.put("NYC", 100000);

 aCity = new City();
 result.put("Boston", 500);

 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class CityMap {
    static Map < String, Integer > buildTable() {
        Map < String, Integer > result = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
        result.put("NYC", 100000);
        result.put("Boston", 500);
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map < String, Integer > cityTable = buildTable();
    }
}
```

Command is not defined, creating instance variables not to use them will do nothing at all, method can not be declared inside method; only inside class - you can declare class inside method (inner class) and method inside that class.