# /MyClass.java:7: error: ';' expected Map<String, Integer> map = Map<String, Integer> () ;

Tags: java

I am trying to do this function

```
import java.util.Map;
public class MyClass {

public static Map<String, Integer> runQuery(Integer x,Integer y){
    
    Map<String, Integer> map = Map<String, Integer> () ;
    map.put("key1", x);
    map.put("key2", y);
    return map;
}
    public  void main(String args[]) {
      int x=10;
      int y=25;
      int z=x+y;
      Map<String, Integer> result = runQuery(3, 4);
      

      System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + z);
      System.out.println("first val = " + result.get("key1"));
    }

}
```

however, I am getting this error:

```
/MyClass.java:7: error: ';' expected
    Map<String, Integer> map = Map<String, Integer> () ;
```

I am referring to this answer:
[Why is there the compile error, " ; expected " for my Java Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823132/why-is-there-the-compile-error-expected-for-my-java-code)
it seems that it's mentioned that the method should be outside of the main method, which is the case in my code, I don't know what I am missing?

Comment: Basically there are lots of different problems that could cause the compiler to report that error.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here:

- `Map` is an interface, so you can't create an instance of it. You need to specify a concrete type.
- You've missed out the `new` part used to call a constructor.

It should be:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

... or using type inference:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

(You'll need to import `java.util.HashMap`, or you could use a different map implementation, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @jon-skeets answer, the `static` flag for the main methode is missing:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {...}
```